# Creating new conditional column based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, analytics

I want to create a new column (3rd column) in which I want to add 1 or 0 depending on following condition:

1. If column 1 and column 2 have the same value, then enter 1 in the 3rd column
2. If value doesn't match, then use 0.

How can I write this code doing this using Pandas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: provide minimal and reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpys where function which works quickly.

```
df['matched'] = np.where((df['col1'] == df['col2']), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way of getting `1`s and `0`s:

```py
df['matched'] = df['col1'].eq(df['col2']).astype(int)
```